# Bigcommerce Auth Callback /w PHP API

Tags: php, curl, bigcommerce

pulling my hair our with this bigcommerce Auth callback (part of the new API).
I have tried both regular PHP API and the latest branch found here https://github.com/maetl/bigcommerce-api-php/tree/f43e652c71550f9074dbf696c740b30651110051 which is suppose to support OAUTH.

I am using the demo code here https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/callback under php to begin. I have setup my app correctly etc however my php is erroring without that.The below onwards is using the OAUTH branch linked as the original has functions this code attempts to call which don't exist.

Here is my code...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/bigcommerce/bigcommerce.php';

use Bigcommerce\Api\Connection;

$tokenUrl = "https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token";
$connection = new Connection();
$connection->useUrlencoded();
$response = $connection->post($tokenUrl, array(
    "client_id" => "#myid",
    "client_secret" => "#mysecret",
    "redirect_url" => "http://#myoauthurl",
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "code" => $request->get("code"),
    "scope" => $request->get("scope"),
    "context" => $request->get("context"),
));

$token = $response->access_token;
?>
```

This moans about the 'get' on the last 3 parts of the array first with an error like this...

```
Notice: Undefined variable: request in /var/www/integrations/bigcommerce/oauth2.php on line 18 Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/integrations/bigcommerce/oauth2.php on line 18
```

To remove those i manually added these...

```
"code" => $_GET["code"],
"scope" => $_GET["scope"],
"context" => $_GET["context"],
```

With these changes I get the following errors.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with message 'failed setting cipher list' in /var/www/libraries/bigcommerce/bigcommerce.php:95 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/libraries/bigcommerce/bigcommerce.php(169): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->handleResponse() #1 /var/www/integrations/bigcommerce/oauth.php(21): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->post('https://login.b...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/libraries/bigcommerce/bigcommerce.php on line 95
```

The above reference to handleReponse() which seems to be issues with the CURL operations in the library.
It also refers to cipher list which has been a previous problem which requires

```
Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);
```

I can attach the correct classes here to get them to be picked up though I doesn't seem to set the cipher for this part as it continues to moan.

Has anyone else had a further luck on the above or have other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up using CURL to achieve this, rather than make it more difficult that it needs to be with the API.

Like below...

```
$data = array(
    "client_id" => "",
    "client_secret" => "",
    "redirect_uri" => "http://",
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "code" => $_GET["code"],
    "scope" => $_GET["scope"],
    "context" => $_GET["context"],
);
$postfields = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init();                    
$url = "https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$obj = json_decode($output);
$access_token = $obj->{'access_token'};
$scope = $obj->{'scope'};
$id =  $obj->{'user'}->{'id'};
$email =  $obj->{'user'}->{'email'};
$context = $obj->{'context'};
```

Comment: Hello, I know this post is a couple months old, but I have been looking at the BigCommerce OAuth Documentation and I am so confused about the first step. I have used OAuth in the past and I understand what to do after you get the authorization code (exchange for token, makes requests etc), but where are you initially supposed to direct your users to login?

Comment: You don't. They are logged into Bigcommerce and they click on 'apps' and they OAUTH into your application. Ie use their Bigcommerce login to get into you site. Does this make sense?

Comment: Oh I see. So this isn't something you can have outside of Bigcommerce? I was thinking this is something you can integrate into a standalone application, but they would have to first log in to their bigcommerce account and then access your application.